# Absolutely position a CSS3 keyframe animation

Tags: css, css-animations

http://jsfiddle.net/Wdrgv/

So I want to put this bad animation at the bottom of the screen. Simple enough, right?

Nope. When I put `position: absolute` on the `marquee-container`, the animation seems to disappear off the screen.

I figure I'm doing something really stupid here, but I can't see what.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that when you apply the absolute positioning to the container, `'display: block;` no longer stretches it to 100% of its container's width, and since it has no relatively-positioned contents to define its dimensions, it relies solely on explicitly defined values (`height: 24px`) or zero if none exist. I've fixed the problem for you by defining `width: 100%` for your containing element. I've also added a few tweaks to make the size and behavior of your marquee a little more robust given varying text lengths:

http://jsfiddle.net/Wdrgv/2/

Comment: Hm. Not bad, but it doesn't seem to actually display all the text if it's longer than the page.

Comment: [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/Wdrgv/5/). I've added a touch of Javascript to determine how long the 'track' needs to be in order for the contained text to cycle across the page exactly one time per animation cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by changing from `absolute` to `fixed` and applying `bottom:0px;` to it.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wdrgv/1/

Comment: Why would you want it `absolute` anyway? Don't you want it stuck to the bottom always?

Comment: Because `fixed` will always remain there, whereas `absolute` won't

Comment: If you want to use `absolute` you may need to use some javascript/jquery, or start from the `top`